# Hadoop message format

Tags: hadoop

I'm trying to look into the interaction protocol between Hadoop modules, ie. the message format between **Job Tracker** and **Task Tracker** (for MRv1). I expect some well-defined formats for such message (like [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ipv4/ipv4_packet_structure.htm) for IP packet format). However, I cannot find any hints after searching for a while. Could anyone kindly point me where I should look for this? The relevant source code snippet could also be helpful (like [this](https://github.com/hanborq/hadoop/blob/master/src/hdfs/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/protocol/DatanodeProtocol.java#L50) for the underlining file system -- HDFS).

Many thanks!

Comment: Why are you using MRv1 instead of YARN?

Comment: @tk421  I just want to start from a simpler case. It's totally fine to have the same information for YARN.